# Find K nearest neighbors, starting from a distance matrix

Tags: r, sorting, matrix, distance, knn

I'm looking for a well-optimized function that accepts an `n X n` distance matrix and returns an `n X k` matrix with the indices of the `k` nearest neighbors of the ith datapoint in the ith row.

I find a gazillion different `R` packages that let you do KNN, but they all seem to include the distance computations along with the sorting algorithm within the same function.  In particular, for most routines the main argument is the original data matrix, not a distance matrix. In my case, I'm using a nonstandard distance on mixed variable types, so I need to separate the sorting problem from the distance computations.

This is not exactly a daunting problem -- I obviously could just use the `order` function inside a loop to get what I want (see my solution below), but this is far from optimal.  For example, the `sort` function with `partial = 1:k` when `k` is small (less than 11) goes much faster, but unfortunately returns only sorted values rather than the desired indices.

Comment: `library(class)` has a `knn` function.  Maybe check that out.  It's a classification package.

Comment: yes, I was looking at `class::knn`. Like the others, it takes raw data and applied the Euclidean distance. I don't see a way to give it a distance matrix directly.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://davetang.org/muse/2013/08/15/distance-matrix-computation/).  `straight_distance <- function(p,q){sqrt((p-q)^2)}`  Not sure if that's it, but you might find something on that page.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use [FastKNN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FastKNN/FastKNN.pdf) CRAN package (although it is not well documented). It offers `k.nearest.neighbors` function where an arbitrary distance matrix can be given. Below you have an example that computes the matrix you need.

```
# arbitrary data
train <- matrix(sample(c("a","b","c"),12,replace=TRUE), ncol=2) # n x 2
n = dim(train)[1]
distMatrix <- matrix(runif(n^2,0,1),ncol=n) # n x n

# matrix of neighbours
k=3
nn = matrix(0,n,k) # n x k
for (i in 1:n)
   nn[i,] = k.nearest.neighbors(i, distMatrix, k = k)
```

> Notice: You can always check Cran packages list for Ctrl+F='knn'
>   related functions:
>   https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html

Answer (score 0):

For the record (I won't mark this as the answer), here is a quick-and-dirty solution.  Suppose `sd.dist` is the special distance matrix.  Suppose `k.for.nn` is the number of nearest neighbors.

```
n = nrow(sd.dist)
knn.mat = matrix(0, ncol = k.for.nn, nrow = n)
knd.mat = knn.mat
for(i in 1:n){
  knn.mat[i,] = order(sd.dist[i,])[1:k.for.nn]
  knd.mat[i,] = sd.dist[i,knn.mat[i,]]
}
```

Now `knn.mat` is the matrix with the indices of the `k` nearest neighbors in each row, and for convenience `knd.mat` stores the corresponding distances.

Comment: This considers that the nearest neighbor of a point is the point itself, since you don't remove the point in the `order` function.