# Calculate nearest neighbor distance between data points within a previously identified Kmeans cluster in R

Tags: r, lapply, k-means, spatstat

I would like to use nndist.ppx() to calculate distance to nearest neighbor within a given Kmeans cluster (df$cluster is as.factor). The clusters are first identified using kmeans(df,2), and I then cbind the cluster vector to original df, and then convert it to class ppx using ppx(df,simplify=F) because df is 3D (xyz) and nndist() requires class ppx.

The problem is that I can only get nndist.ppx to calculate the distance to all the points in the df irregardless of cluster. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39963169/r-function-to-calculate-nearest-neighbor-distance-given-inconsistent-constrain) is close to what I'm looking for in that distance is being calculated with a restraint.

Start with practice data which is a list with 2 elements of class df

```
library(spatstat)
library(stats)

df_a1 <- data.frame(X = c(9,9,10,10,17,20,22,25,40,40,42), 
Y=c(10,10,11,11,105,106,108,109,112,113,114), Z=c(1,1,1,1,3,4,4,6,8,8,8))

df_a2 <- data.frame(X = c(9,9,10,10,15,22,26,30,40,40,42), 
Y=c(10,10,11,11,105,106,108,109,112,113,114), Z=c(1,1,1,1,5,5,4,5,7,7,8))

list_a <- list(df_a1,df_a2)
df_a_list_names<-c("control", "variable")
```

Run kmeans clustering:
Here is my Kmeans fxn which also cbinds the Kmeans cluster vector to the original df.  I then lapply the kmeans_fxn over list of dfs.  The output is stored in a new list.

```
kmeans_fxn<-function(x){
kmeans(x,(3))->results
results$cluster->cluster
cluster->x$cluster
as.factor(x$cluster)->x$cluster
return(x)
}

lapply(list_a, kmeans_fxn)->kmean_results_list
```

Calculate distance of nearest neighbor:
Here is fxn I wrote to calculate distance between each data point and its top 2 nearest neighbors.  I then lapply the fxn to previously created list

```
distance_fxn<-function(x){
x<-ppx(x, simplify=F)->df.ppx
nndist.ppx(df.ppx,k=2)->x
as.data.frame(x)->x
return(x)
}

lapply(kmean_results_list, distance_fxn)->nearest_list
```

The output is distance to nearest neighbor within entire df irregardless of cluster (I repeated without cluster column and output was the same...not shown).

Also, I tried this

```
kmeans_results_list[[1]]->fob
ppx(fob, simplify=F)->fob.ppx
by(fob.ppx[[1]], cluster, function(x) nndist.ppx(fob.ppx, k=2))
```

and this but neither worked

```
by(fob.ppx, fob.ppx[[1]], function(x) nndist.ppx(fob.ppx, k=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of treating the cluster label as a coordinate, treat it as a mark. Use as.ppp to convert your data frame to a two-dimensional point pattern (class ppp) with categorical marks. Then divide this pattern X into a list of patterns using Y <-split(X). Then compute nearest neighbour distances within each cluster by D <- lapply(Y, nndist). If you want the distances in their original order use unsplit(D, marks(X)).

Comment: Does this approach ignore the Z value when calculating distance? (the original df is 3D).  Y[1] shows Z as a mark variable.  It did successfully split by cluster.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn’t clear to me that Z is meant to be a third spatial coordinate. In that case, you should make the data frame df with columns headed x,y,z,cluster. Then create the 3D point pattern X <- ppx(df, coord.type=c(rep(“spatial”, 3), “mark”)). Then proceed as before.