# knn using cosine and jaccard distance

Tags: r, knn

I am new to R and Machine Learning. I am running a KNN classification using the Euclidian distance. I was wondering how can I use cosine and jaccard distance instead of Euclidian in R? Are there any packages I can use ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

first of all what you can do is run from within an R-session

```
library(sos)

findFn("knn", maxPages=10, sortby="MaxScore")
```

to search for knn packages by maxscore ( you can adjust the parameters accordingly ).

If you don't find a package that offers the cosine or jaccard distance, then I would suggest to first compute the distance matrix and then give this as input to the knn.

There are some packages like [kNN](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dbscan/versions/1.1-1/topics/kNN) or [FastKnn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449726/find-k-nearest-neighbors-starting-from-a-distance-matrix) which accept a distance matrix as input ( you can google this using : "distance matrix knn r" ).

Lastly the [KernelKnn](https://github.com/mlampros/KernelKnn) allows the computation of the jaccard distance but only for binary data (I'm the author, you can have a look to the other distance metrics too).

I hope it helps.