# Custom distance matrix with KNN

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, knn

I need to get k nearest neighbors from distance matrix. Example:
I have two "training" vectors `"a" <- c(1,1)` and `"b" <- c(2,2)` which are two dimensional vectors. I have to classify `c(3,3)` and I didn't have regular distance because numbers are codes for characteristics, and `distance(2,3) > distance(1,3)`...so `c(3,3)` has `"a"` for nearest neighbor. Later I have to generalize and output n nearest neighbors, but only for one vector at a time.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449726/find-k-nearest-neighbors-starting-from-a-distance-matrix) was most promising at first, but when I looked into [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FastKNN/FastKNN.pdf) for `k.nearest.neighbors` I realized it won't help me. I can't do this with Python's scikit-learn, but have some hope for R implementation, any suggestions?
I need speed with this so if I'm going to implement it in high level language I need to do it with some library...I can easily code this up in Python's numpy, but will be almost certainly too slow.

EDIT:

```
library(FNN)
distance_matrix <- matrix( rep( 0, len=9), nrow = 3)
distance_matrix[1,3] <- 2
distance_matrix[3,1] <- 2
distance_matrix[2,3] <- 3
distance_matrix[3,2] <- 3
train <- rbind(c(1,1), c(2,2)
test <- rbind(c(3,3))
y <- c("one", "two")
fit <- knn(train, test, y, distance_matrix, k=1, prob=TRUE)
result <- data.frame(test, pred=fit, prob=attr(fit, "prob"))
```

But when I look at dataframe `result` I see result based on euclidian metric or something alike, not my distance matrix.

Comment: Can you please make this a [reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (SO help ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It sounds like you're asking for a software recommendation, specifically [off-topic for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you have specific code that is mis-behaving, then please include it and be clear why it is misbehaving. (And a small request: please place this reproducible code within a [preformatted code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't do it at first because I'm looking for correct package.

Comment: did you find anything? @spartan